# Golang ascending order

Tags: go

I have a Go Language question here, is there any much better way to answer the answer in coding Golang compare to mine below?

Mangkuk is a list consisting of maximal size Sudu.
Sudu is a permutation of consecutive integers, possibly with repeated items.

A Cawan is a Mangkuk where each Sudu is sorted in the ascending order.
Write a function, MakeCawan(→Mangkuk), to sort the given Mangkuk into a Cawan.

```html
For example,
MakeCawan([21, 20, 18, 20, 18, 20, 19]),
MakeCawan([21, 2000000, 18, 20, 18, 20, 19]),
MakeCawan([21, 20, 18, 20, 18, 20, 1900000])
should produce, respectively,
[18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21],
[21, 2000000, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20],
[20, 21, 18, 20, 18, 20, 1900000].
```

```js
package main

    import (
     "fmt"
     "sort"
    )

    func main() {
     sl := []string{"MakeCawan"}
     sort.Sort(sort.StringSlice(sl))
     fmt.Println(sl)
     
     sl1 := []string{"MakeCawan"}
     sort.Sort(sort.StringSlice(sl1))
     fmt.Println(sl1)
     
     sl2 := []string{"MakeCawan"}
     sort.Sort(sort.StringSlice(sl2))
     fmt.Println(sl2)
     
     intSlice := []int{21,20,18,20,18,20,19}
     sort.Sort(sort.IntSlice(intSlice))
     fmt.Println(intSlice)

    }
```

The Output:

https://play.golang.org/p/tsE0BtMRos_9

Comment: When you talk about `better` do you mean better in terms of Time/Space Complexity OR better in terms of readability?

Comment: In terms of readability and working method/solution @SauravPrakash

Comment: How is  
`
[21, 2000000, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20],
[20, 21, 18, 20, 18, 20, 1900000].
`
in sorted order?

Comment: I suggest you provide the link of orignal question, and read the question more carefully (or use a more capable translator). Your code does not make sense with the question description.

Comment: That's the only question provided. Start from the "Sudu is a ... until 1900000] " no other details @leafbebop

Comment: yeah.. i got confuse with that to be honest on how [21, 2000000, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20 ] is in sorted order. but these were provided by the questionnaire. isn't 21 suppose to be at the back? But no idea about this. @SauravPrakash

Comment: So what exactly is a `mangkuk`? And why are you sorting the string `"MakeCawan"`?

Comment: oh yes, mangkuk is a list consisting of maximal size Sudu. @leafbebop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a little bit tricky: It does not ask you to sort the whole slice (or mangkuk in its own term); it asks you to first recognize all successive intervals (with possible repeated elements) which is called sudu, and then sort each sudu.

```
func makeCawan(mangkuk []int) []int {
    for now, n := 0, len(mangkuk); now < n; {
        min := mangkuk[now]
        max := min
        head := now
    loop:
        for now++; now < n; now++ {
            switch x := mangkuk[now]; {
            case x < min-1 || x > max+1:
                sort(mangkuk[head:now], min, max)
                break loop
            case x == min-1:
                min = x
            case x == max+1:
                max = x
            }
        }
        if now >= n {
            sort(mangkuk[head:now], min, max)
        }
    }

    return mangkuk
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/z3TGWnWnrVY

Answer (score -1):

Answering this question assuming you want to sort a slice of int which are consecutive and repetitive.

Simply sorting the slice is a readable solution but would take O(nlgn) using a comparsion based sorting algorithm for a slice of length n.

We can use a better performin algorithm with O(n) auxillary space.
Algorithm:
 1. Iterate over array A and find min and max in.
 2. Create an array B with length max-min+1.
 3. Iterate over A and store count of each element in B
i.e `B[A[i] - min]++` .
 4. Now iterate over B and print  `i + min`, B[i] times.

Time Complexity - O(n)

https://play.golang.org/p/rptgMpWdKCX

Note that this loop is also O(n) where n is length of actual input array.

```
for i:=0;i<len(b);i++{
        for b[i] != 0{
            fmt.Printf("%v ", i + min)
            b[i]--
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, it does not solve the problem. Even sample input fails.

Comment: Thank you Saurav for the help. Just about the [21, 2000000, 18, 20, 18, 20, 19], it is less possibility to get into [21, 2000000, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20] since it is suppose to be in ascending order. Don't know how the questionnaire can be like that.. but thank you Saurav. :)